# How do I rebase in git?

Tags: git-rebase, git

Can anyone please help me out doing a rebase on git?
It's really confusing, I'm not able to understand its functionality.
I want to rebase branch on master origin.

How do I do that? I also want to squash commits into one.

Comment: check this out: http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html It's a tutorial on squash commits using rebase.

Comment: i have read that article and also implemented it,but after doing this i am not able to see my commits that i have done earlier,when doing git log.

Comment: Can you describe in non-git terms what you are trying to do?  Bring changes from master into your branch? Merge your changes back into master? Clean up your history but continue working on your branch?

Comment: I think there is [plenty of documentation](http://google.com/search?q=git%20squash) on this. Please elaborate why this is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the manual [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Swith on your branch:

```
 git checkout myBranch
```

Rebase it on your master:

```
 git rebase master
```

If you want to squash some commits (for example on the last 10 commits) you've do an interactive rebase while you're on your branch:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

Then in your editor you can use the `squash` keyword to meld a commit in it previous commit.

Comment: i first checkout to my branch,and then executed git rebase origin master,and it returns "git rebase origin master is up to date".Can you please tell me what does it mean?

Comment: It means you already did a rebase. So your branch commits are in top of your master `HEAD`